# I wanna trigger an action when user start to scroll in ios from third party

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, uiscrollviewdelegate

I have two layers: Application and Framework. The application layer has all of the views. The framework layer doesnt have any views but when the application layer calls into the framework layer, an argument with type `UIViewController` is passed. I want to detect when user start scrolling in this `UIViewController`.

By the way, I have to call only framework methods such as `viewDidLoad`.

I tried detect all ScrollViews and delegates with my delegation classes, but this method disabled application layer protocols.

Do you have any suggestions to detect the scrolling event?

Application Layer :

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
   super.viewDidLoad()
   let myObject = MyFramework()
   myObject.execute(viewcontroller:self)
}
```

Framework Layer :

```
public func execute(viewcontroller:UIViewController){
   let event = eventController() // which is my controller  for delegation
   viewcontroller.addChildViewController(event)
   if(isContainScrollView(view:viewcontroller)){
     let scrollView:UIScrollView = returnScrollView(parent: view) as! UIScrollView
     scrollView.contentSize.width = CGFloat(self.width)
     scrollView.contentSize.height = CGFloat(self.height)
     scrollView.delegate = event as UIScrollViewDelegate 
   }
}
```

Comment: Please post the code you tried

Comment: @Happypig375 . I added the code I tried

Comment: There are many unknown variables here, if you’ll give us a simple example that compiles and focuses on the core of the problem it would be easier to answer your question

Comment: Sorry for the late answer. 
I prepare repository which is include example framework and example app. 
Scenario : Open that file : Ecoomerce -->HomePage --> View --> ProductCollectionViewController --> viewDidLoad 
and comment line 29 and 30 and then deploy project. You will see you able to click all items . But when you remove the comment from 29and30 (line) and then deploy the project you will see you cant click any of item. You will see the message at console which is " Something happens".
That is the problem.

here is link  : https://github.com/selinhangisi/question-scroll @Niv